# TableView setRowFactory CSS selector

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I want to render a complete row in a TableView dependent on the item in this row. I use TableView.setRowFactory, but it seems that this is not working.

As you can see in the code, the row should be rendered with a different text color, if the last name of the person in this row is "Smith".

The same code is working, if I use TableColumn.setCellFactory. But I don't want to copy the necessary code in all different cell factories.

**Where is my mistake?**

```
public class TableViewTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Scene scene = new Scene(createContents());
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("test.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Pane createContents() {
        final ObservableList<Person> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person("John", "Smith"), new Person("Mary", "Smith"),
                new Person("William", "Young"));
        final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>(items);
        final TableColumn<Person, String> c1 = new TableColumn<>("First name");
        c1.setCellValueFactory(p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getFName()));
        final TableColumn<Person, String> c2 = new TableColumn<>("Last name");
        c2.setCellValueFactory(p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getLName()));
        table.getColumns().setAll(c1, c2);
        table.setRowFactory(param -> new TableRow<Person>() {
            protected void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                getStyleClass().remove("own-cell");
                if (item != null && item.getLName().equals("Smith")) {
                    getStyleClass().add("own-cell");
                }
            };
        });
        return new HBox(table);
    }
}
```

This is the simple style sheet test.css with only 1 style:

```
.table-row-cell:filled .own-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: cyan;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is incorrect: the selector

```
.table-row-cell:filled .own-cell
```

selects an element with style class `own-cell` that is a *descendant* of an element with style class `table-row-cell` (and has pseudoclass `filled`).

You need to select any `table-cell` that is a descendant of an element with both style class `own-cell` *and* `table-row-cell`.

The following will do this:

```css
.own-cell.table-row-cell:filled .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: cyan;
}
```

Note there is no space between `.own-cell` and `.table-row-cell`.

As an aside, if you have a CSS class that can be switched on or off with a boolean expression, it's usually easier to use a custom `PseudoClass` than to add and remove style classes from a list. You might consider the following modification:

```
    PseudoClass ownCell = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("own-cell");
    table.setRowFactory(param -> new TableRow<Person>() {
        protected void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(ownCell, item != null && item.getLName().equals("Smith"));
        };
    });
```

for which you use the CSS

```css
.table-row-cell:filled:own-cell .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: cyan;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and helping answer! I'm new to style sheets and will test your recommendation of PseudoClass.

Comment: @GeneralMartok You're welcome. I added another option to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the use of a custom PseudoClass. It's indeed easier to use and imho more logical.